# Docker-compose + Django on AWS C9

Tags: django, docker-compose, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to use a docker container to run a django application on the cloud base IDE from AWS (AWS C9).
The application is started correctly and the development server is started on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
However when browsing to the public URL of the cloud 9 application I'm getting the error 'no application seems to be running'.
When creating a django application without docker, the preview on AWS coud 9 works fine.

Are there any addtional settings required to get the cloud 9 preview to work?
This is my docker-compose file.

```
   
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```